# Retrofit call enqueue doesn't reach any of them "onResponse" or "onFailure"

Tags: java, android, retrofit

```
public static void getAccuWeatherData( String appId, final InterfaceWeatherCallbackListener listener) {

        InterfaceWeatherApi mWeatherApi = ApiService.getRetrofitInstance(BASE_DEV_URL_ACCU_WEATHER).create(InterfaceWeatherApi.class);
        Call<List<AccuWeatherModel>> call = mWeatherApi.getAccuWeatherData(appId);
        Log.d("call",""+call);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<AccuWeatherModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<AccuWeatherModel>> call, Response<List<AccuWeatherModel>> response) {
                Log.e("response",""+response);
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    if (listener != null)
                        Log.e("Base Url","listener"+listener);
                        listener.getWeatherData(response.body().get(0), true, "");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<AccuWeatherModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                listener.getWeatherData(null, false, t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: are you seeing any error in logcat?

Comment: you should log your errors in onFailure, that's actually what Log.e is for

Comment: It doesn't reach to onFailure and onRequest, and I am getting retrofit object but not be able to reach to Response. I am not getting any error.   I get OKHttp

Comment: Yes I am getting this error. "E/Error: Errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Comment: You are receiving array from response. check your model class and response json.

Comment: @SumayyaMunir As per the shared error, the API response root is JSONObject, but you have written as JSONArray `List<AccuWeatherModel>`. Share the API response JSON for the complete solution.